# does poll system call know if remote socket closed or disconnected?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, polling

int rc = poll(fds, 1, -1);
let us say the remote peer goes down. socket breaks here.
In this case will the poll system call return -1 or
will return > 0 and report the disconnect as an error event on the FD.

Also, what would poll return on 0 timeout.
int rc = poll(fds, nfds, 0);

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't. All it knows is that something happened on the socket, and whether that was a read event, a write event, or an error event. Peer disconnect counts as a read event.

Answer (score 3):

If the sockets breaks, `poll()` will return > 0, then you will have to check the return value of `recv` in order to know if the socket is disconnected (`recv()` will return 0 in this case).

> Also, what would poll return on 0 timeout. int rc = poll(fds, nfds,
>   0);

`poll()` will return immediately, and the return value can be >= 0.

You really should read [the `poll()` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), there is all you need to know.

Comment: On 0 timeout, the return value is 0 if there are no events and 1 if there is any event at that moment of time, is it correct?

Comment: @Medicine It's almost true :) The return value of `poll()` is the number of events. So `poll()` will return 1 if there is **one** event at that moment of time, but the return value can be greater than 1 if there is more than 1 event (so the return valueis 0 if there is no events).

Comment: @Medicine That doesn't make sense. The timeout only happens if there are no events. If there are events there is no timeout.

Comment: @EJP got it so the return value can be 0 or 1 if there were events during that point of time

Comment: @Medicine, no, the return value is zero if there were no events, otherwise the number of events, or rather the number of ready sockets, which can be anything from 1 upwards. Do read the documentation, it's all in there.

Comment: This is great. Why use custom "heartbeat" checks when this poll mechanism seems to serve the same purpose?

Comment: @thomas.cloud Why indeed? HTTP doesn't do it, and I don't see any reason for any other protocol to do it either. Maybe one ping-pong on a pooled connection to see if it is still alive before re-using it, as in JDBC and RMI connection pooling.

Answer (score -2):

From the *man* page:

> The field revents is an output parameter, filled by the kernel with the events
> that actually occurred. The bits returned in revents can include any of those
> specified in events, or one of the values POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL.
> (These three bits are meaningless in the events field, and will be set in the
> revents field whenever the corresponding condition is true.)
>
> If none of the events requested (and no error) has occurred for any of the file
> descriptors, then poll() blocks until one of the events occurs.
>
> Return Value
> On success, a positive number is returned; this is the number of structures which
> have nonzero revents fields (in other words, those descriptors with events or
> errors reported). A value of 0 indicates that the call timed out and no file
> descriptors were ready. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

So, it clear says that if there is an error in the FD return value > 0 and the revents field is filled with the appropiate value. POLLERR for example.

Comment: It doesn't 'clear[ly] say that if there is an error in the FD [the] return value > 0'. It say that if there is an incoming error event on the connection the return value is > zero. There's a difference. And an orderly close by the peer isn't an error, it's a read event.